# JS variable which is for an object's value index does not return any value

Tags: javascript, object, key-value

Total lost.

What I want to do is get the array like under below.

0: {run: 'sam'. swim: 'ham'},

1: {run: 'tom', swim:'bill'},

2: {run: 'jim', swim: 'sam},

......

but when I put the code here, `obj[name1[o]] = name2[some(name2)];`, especially  value part, doesn't work.

why I cannot use a variable for the index of an object's value in this sentence?

```js
const arr = [];
const obj = {}

var name1 = ['run','swim'];
var name2 = ['sam','ham','tom','bill','jim'];

function some(a){
  for(var n = 0; n < a.length; n++){
  n  //simplified calculating
  }  
}

for(var a = 0; a<3; a++){
  arr[a] = obj;
  for(var o=0; o<2; o++){
  obj[name1[o]] = name2[some(name2)];
  }
}


console.log(arr);
```

Comment: how many objects to you want to get in the result set?

Answer (score 1):

You could take all names and all keys and take a calculated length for iteration.

The value are taken with the [reminder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) and the length of the array to prevent undefined values.

```js
var keys = ['run', 'swim'],
    names = ['sam', 'ham', 'tom', 'bill', 'jim'],
    result = [],
    length = Math.ceil(names.length / keys.length) * keys.length;

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    let j = Math.floor(i / keys.length);
    if (!result[j]) result[j] = {};
    result[j][keys[i % keys.length]] = names[i % names.length];
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks and bit more question. index no.3 does not appear like {run: “jim”, swim: “sam”} how can I make a loop for this case?